# Asymptotic of an improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, asymptotics, improper-integrals

I found myself stuck with an "elementary" claim in an article. A simplified version of the problem is :
Let $p : [0,1]\to [0,1]$ be a continuous and non decreasing function such that $p(0)=0$ and $\int_0^1 (\log \frac{1}{u})^{1/2} \, dp(u) < + \infty$. Show that
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\int_0^h (\log \frac{1}{u})^{1/2} \, dp(u)}{p(h) (\log \frac{1}{h})^{1/2}}
$$
exists and is finite.

I think that a good idea is to use integration by parts formula which gives
$$
\int_0^h (\log \frac{1}{u})^{1/2}\, dp(u) = p(h) (\log \frac{1}{h})^{1/2} + \int_0^h \frac{p(u)}{2u(\log \frac{1}{u})^{1/2}} du,
$$
but I don't see how to conclude...

Comment: The same question was posted and answered in MathOverflow. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383636/asymptotic-of-an-improper-integral/383717?noredirect=1#comment976981_383717